# Quarkus Microprofile JWT - Alternate quarkus.smallrye-jwt.auth-mechanism

Tags: oauth, jwt, quarkus, microprofile, jose4j

I'm trying out the [Quarkus JWT](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/master/using-jwt-rbac) quickstart. But when I use the token that I normally use in my Spring application. I get the following error.

> rejected due to invalid claims. Additional details: [[17] Unexpected
> exception thrown from validator org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.IssValidator:
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.IssValidator.expectedValue(IssValidator.java:72);
> org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.IssValidator.validate(IssValidator.java:59);
> ...omitted..., [14] No Subject (sub) claim is present

Looks like the Microprofile JWT auth spec, specifies the Subject (sub) as one of the minimum claims required in a JWT. So, is there an alternate JWT auth mechanism that can be used, that doesn't require the Subject claim? i.e any other parameter that can be passed to the `quarkus.smallrye-jwt.auth-mechanism`
property, other than `MP_JWT`?

Comment: The error is stating that the `sub` claim is missing.  Did you set this claim when you created the JWT?  I don't know your implementation, but maybe it requires that `sub` be assigned.

Comment: It is passed to my service from another service. And, the `sub` claim doesn't seem to be present when I decode the JWT. That's why I was wondering if the validation for that claim could be disabled, since it seems to happen inside a validate method `IssValidator.validate` , if possible.

Comment: Hello, Quarkus uses the `sub` claim to make the authentication of the user (to create the Principal object). Today there appears to be no way to use a different claim. I will raise this issue to the Quarkus mailing list.

Comment: @loicmathieu, thank you :)